# Use PHP to extract data from an object literal in the middle of a JavaScript program

Tags: javascript, php

I have a JS file with the following assignment of an object literal to a variable in it.

```
var data = {
  title:"My webpage",
};
```

I want to access this JS file from PHP to read this data so I can output it into HTML.

Since this is not JSON, the following does not work.

```
$str = file_get_contents("data/data.js");
$object = json_decode($str, true);
echo $object['title'];
```

How would I access that file and write out the 'title' to HTML using a PHP file?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/v8js.examples.php you can try to run javascript engine.

Comment: That's *not* a JSON object.  It a JavaScript object literal.  It's got *nothing* to do with JSON whatsoever.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't send this data to your PHP server using ajax or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't use a .json file?

If not a really quick and easy/dirty solution would be to have a file like:

**data.json**

```
{
  "title":"My webpage"
}
```

And then just get it the way you are trying to.

Comment: No I cannot use a JSON file because the client returns all this data wrapped in a JS function :/

Comment: You should quote your keys too, so it's *valid* JSON.

Comment: @RocketHazmat you're totally right, i think that answer was kinda quick and dirty too, edited it. :)

Comment: @Komsomol then I guess the easiest solution would be to use jquery ajax to send the data to your php.

the jquery documentation is very well written and provides you with everything you need:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/